# Exchange Online Message Records Management - Online Archive by Modified Date?

Tags: microsoft-office-365

So I followed the Microsoft documentation to get this setup --> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/set-up-an-archive-and-deletion-policy-for-mailboxes?view=o365-worldwide. Specifically I'm looking to take any Exchange items more than 2 years old and move them over into the users' Online Archive.

After implementing this I now see that the item age is being determined as creation date, not modified date. And punching back into the configuration steps, there doesn't seem to be an option to change that logic. I'll include a screen shot of the M365 portal page where I configure the retention tag. Also included is a Powershell command showing a TriggerForRetention property for the retention tag. This property can't be modified, so I'm apparently stuck.

Going into the Data Lifecycle Management M365 Purview area I see there I can likewise create retention labels and policy. But there doesn't appear to be an option to move items modified before a threshold to the users' Online Archive. The only option is to do nothing or to delete the items.

Anyone offering tips on how to best facilitate what I'm looking to do?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opened a ticket with Microsoft Support. Apparently this isn't an option (yet). The only retention policy that will automatically move items over X days old to the user's online archive has to be based on creation date. Modified date isn't an option.